# Полнотекстовый поиск от начала строки

Tags: php, mysql, sql, полнотекстовый-поиск

В БД имеются три записи с текстом "*Город*", "*Новый город*" и "*Старый город*". Делаем запрос для полнотекстового поиска:

```
SELECT id_city, MATCH (name_city) AGAINST ('город*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relev 
FROM tab1 
WHERE MATCH (name_city) AGAINST ('город*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
ORDER BY relev DESC
```

Он возвращает все три записи содержащие слово "*Город*", не смотря на то, что я поставил оператор поиска " * " в конец искомой строки. Задача переделать запрос так, чтобы он искал строго от начала строки, а не от середины или конца строки.

В результате записи с текстом "*Новый город*" и "*Старый город*" должны исключаться из результатов поиска, потому как искомое слово "*город*" не стоит в начале этих записей.

Comment: тогда, может WHERE name_city LIKE 'город%'  ?

Comment: splash58, да, это определённо будет работать. Но как бы хотелось избежать использования LIKE.

Comment: MATCH  врядли быстрее

Comment: splash58, дело в том, что у меня более миллиона записей в БД. Поэтому я сейчас решил переехать от LIKE к использованию FULLTEXT.

Comment: Здесь: http://7d3.ru/wiki/330 имеется весьма интересный способ ускорения LIKE при помощи MATCH. Испробую этот вариант.

Comment: Меня пока бог миловал от таких объемов, но все равно, интересно :) Спасибо